# How to list multiple objects from laravel to vue using javascript filter function?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, object, laravel-5

I am passing multiple `objects` from `laravel` to `vue` and want to populate my vue objects with values given from the database.

The data from laravel:

[image]

Vue objects:

```
  storeName: {},
  storeUrl: {},
  appName: {},
  price: {},
  share: {},
```

Where the data comes:

```
  mounted() {
  axios.get('/dashboard/affiliates')
    .then(res => {
      let data = res.data;

      this.storeName = data.affiliates.shop_name;
      console.log(data.affiliates);
    })
```

As I understand, one of the bests ways would be to populate my vue objects it would be with filter function of javascript, but quite don't get it fully and don't know how to do it.

How could I populate vue objects with data that later on I could list them to the view in a v-for?

Comment: could you explain your wishes?

Comment: How could I populate vue objects with data that later on I could list them to the view in a v-for?

Answer (score 0):

- First use a compute function to link view and when you change storeName the app detect changes and paint again
- Second, to make a array of shop_name use .filter to filter and them a .map to adapt your data

My advice is you store all data on vue data side, and on your computed method filter data and optional parse data, Also you can access to data with template, so you can parse data on template.

Something like this

```
export default {
    name: 'loquesea',
    data: {
        affiliates: []
    },
    mounted() {
          axios.get('/dashboard/affiliates')
        .then(res => {
            let data = res.data;
            this.affiliates = data.affiliates;
        })
    },
    computed: {
        getStoresName() {
            return this.affiliates.filter(() => {
                // what you want
                return true;
            }).map((affiliate) => {
                return affiliate.shop_name;
            })
        }
    }
}
```

on your template.html

```
<ul id="example-1">
  <li v-for="storeName in getStoresName">
    {{ storeName  }}
  </li>
</ul>
```